# How to compare two regexps in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I’m unit-testing a function which builds a regexp, but using `=` doesn’t work. How can I test that it returns the correct regexp?

Here is what I tried for an empty regexp:

```
(= #"" #"") ; false
(== #"" #"") ; ClassCastException java.util.regex.Pattern cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
(identical? #"" #"") ; false
(.equals #"" #"") ; false
```

Is there a Clojure-ish way to do that, or do I have to convert both regexps to strings then compare them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunatly there is not better way, you just have to use strings

```
user> (= (str #"foo") (str #"foo"))    
true                                   
user> (= (str #"foo") (str #"fooo"))   
false
```

Even this is not perfect because it doesn't catch regular expressions that match the same strings though look different.

```
user> (re-seq #"[a]" "aaaa")       
("a" "a" "a" "a")                  
user> (re-seq #"a" "aaaa")         
("a" "a" "a" "a")
user> (= (str #"a") (str #"[a]"))  
false
```

This is the same reason that **you can't compare functions for equality either**. I suspect that Clojure does not implament `==` for regexes because it would be impractical to determine if the two regexes would match the same strings (or some other idea of equality).

Comment: (+ 1 1) and 2 are two different expressions with the same value. We can think of the value of a regex as the strings it accepts. Different regexes that match the same strings are still different expressions. There is NO algorithm to determine if two general function expressions are equivalent. There are algorithms to determine whether two regular expressions are equivalent, but they are intractable i.e. run in worse than polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

This is tied to the fact that pattern in clojure internally uses java.util.regex.Pattern. 
If you will try to write a java program to compare two pattern objects like this, it will again return false.

The only way to do it is to do equals on regex Strings.